# Call function from android library

Tags: android, kotlin

According to [UserManager Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager), there's some public methods like the `getUserName()`, when I call the function as below and I compile, I get the error: Unresolved reference: getUserName

```
package com.example

import android.Manifest
import android.os.UserManager

class DeviceInfo(private val context: Context) {

    val userName: String
        get(){
            return UserManager.getUserName()
        }


}
```

How can I call this public function in Kotlin?

Comment: According to [UserManager Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager) that's an instance method.

Comment: It's also _"only available to applications on the system image and that it requires the `android.permission.MANAGE_USERS` or `android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS_PRIVILEGED` permissions"_, according to the docs for [`UserManager#getUserName`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager#getUserName()).

Comment: @Edric I've wrote in manifest the permission, but the App doesn't run yet

Comment: @DaveNewton what that means? Sorry..

Comment: @AlexandreMartinsMontebelo It means you call `getUserName()` on an *instance* of `UserManager`. It's not a static method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code, it should solve your problem

```
class DeviceInfo(private val context: Context) {
    val userName: String
        get(){
            val um = context.getSystemService(Context.USER_SERVICE) as UserManager
            return um.userName
        }
}
```